# New laptop and local connections start failing

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'd am stuck with a local postgres connection issue and can't seem to solve it with all the help I could find on the internet :((

I recently changed to a new laptop and have been trying to get my NodeJs app to connect to my local postgres instance for the past week. The connection code I have is:

```
const pgclient = new Client({
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  ssl: false,
  database: 'de***********i6c',

});
```

When I try to run queries in my code, it keeps on timing out at the pgclient.query step:

```
console.log("BEFORE Connection (LOGGED)");
pgclient.query(query, (err, pgres) => {
  Console.log("AFTER Connection(NOT LOGGED)");
...
```

My code hasn't changed since I moved to the new laptop, only perhaps the local environment having changed. What are some of the ways to find out what is going round with the connection here? When I deploy the code to Heroku it works just fine, but I'd like to be able to iterate offline more quickly and safely.

Any tips would be very appreciated!!

Update:
The timeout is unlikely in the database, as the query itself is pretty light. I could connect manually to the DB using pg_isready, no problem. After digging deep and dumping the 'pgclient' client in Node on both my old and new machines, I found this difference:

Old stream:

```
Socket { connecting: true, _hadError: false, _parent: null, _host: 'localhost', _readableState: [ReadableState], readable: false, _events: [Object: null prototype], ...
```

New stream:

```
Socket { connecting: false, _hadError: false, _parent: null, _host: null, _readableState: [ReadableState], _events: [Object: null prototype], ...
```

Everything else is basically the same. I know the above doesn't say much about the cause, but I hope it might indicate possible places where it might gone wrong?

Comment: Are you able to connect to postgres via pgAdmin? Or via console? And second, what is the error message you get?

Comment: @Sergio Yeah no problems with connecting with console or pgAdmin, so no error messages. I have my old laptop next to me and it works just fine there.

Comment: I was asking about what is the error that you get on NodeJS when trying to connecto to pg. Because you should be getting some type of error

Comment: Also, have you checked that `process.env.DATABASE_URL` is updated to your new laptop

Comment: @Sergio yup I checked the DATABASE_URL and it seems to be aligned on the new laptop too.
I added some additional info in the post, as those were the only logs and differences I could spot.

Comment: Found the issue! Somehow my pg npm installation was faulty and I just reinstalled it. Now somehow it's working LOL. Thanks for the help @Sergio!